# Regex:Matching upside down text

Tags: regex

I want to know a regex to match upside down letters. These are a set of noncontiguous Unicode characters that are an approximation of upside down versions of regular lower case characters.

This:

```
[a-z]+
```

would match lower case characters but also matches o in the upside down character list. So can anyone let me know how to match these upside down letters.

Upside Down Letters - Try it [here](http://www.fliptext.org/)

Comment: How the upside down text looks like?

Comment: What is an upside down letter? And what is a downside up letter?

Comment: i think you need to put all the upside down letters inside a character class.

Comment: Edited to make more sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) where you explicitly enumerate the characters you consider "upside down".

Based on the URL you've posted in comments, the upside-down variants of lowercase Latin letters are:

```
[zʎxʍʌnʇsɹbdouɯןʞظıɥbɟǝpɔqɐ]+
```

If you want to match *only Latin letters, which are upside-down variants of other Latin letters*, then:

```
[zxnsbdoubpq]+
```

And if you want to match *only Latin letters, whose upside-down variants are same as the corresponding letter itself*, then:

```
[zxso]+
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually put the upside down letters inside a character class and then make it to repeat one or more times. Because you can't define a range here.

```
[zʎxʍʌnʇsɹbdouɯןʞظıɥbɟǝpɔqɐ]+
```